# moving wordpress blog to new url - gallery images sizes broken

Tags: wordpress

I moved my old site http://traumbad-muenchen.de/referenzen/ to a new one yesterday:
http://bodenmanufaktur-muenchen.de/referenzen/

On the mentioned page you can see that the added gallery (traumbad-muenchen) shows images in the same size BUT the gallery on the new site (bodenmanufaktur-muenchen) shows images with different sizes, which looks strange.

I posted the exactly same code in the new site, but nothing is changing.
I also noticed that I can`t upload new images at all since yesterday to the media libary.

Does anybody know why this bug appeares and how I can change it?

Thanks
BR
Heidi

Comment: If you can't upload images, that sounds like a file permission problem.  Make sure your `wp-content/uploads` directory is writable (by the user your web server runs as).

Comment: As for the appearance, different files are being served on the two sites (eg traumbad shows bad_vollansicht_2-150x170.jpg - the thumbnail - while bodenmanufaktur shows bad_vollansicht_2.jpg - the full sized image).  You say the code's the same, but WordPress is seeing a difference. How did you populate the new database?

Comment: it doesn`t seem to me that it is a problem about differentfiles

Comment: ... about different files. It seems like the plugins functionality does not work any more for whatever reason. Plugin is shortcodes ultimate. If I create a new gallery and look the preview, all images do have the same size, but when I go to add and save it the images do have different sizes. I looked at the code with firebug now, and saw that there is: <div class="su-custom-gallery-slide" data-index="2"> while on the original side there is NO data-index="". Does anybody know what this means? Is there something wrong with the database? What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I was just explaining the difference in appearance - a symptom, not the cause.  Which is why I asked how you populated the new database.  Looking at the raw HTML of the page as it's served (not in firebug, because that shows the DOM after it's been manipulated by JavaScript), there are no `data-index` attributes on either site, so you can ignore that (another symptom).  Did you fix the directory permission problem?  What happens if you recreate you thumbnails (eg with [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/))?  Can you outline the steps you took copying the site?

Comment: ok sorry than I missunderstood you - thanks for your explanation. Yes the directory permission should be fixed now. If I create a new gallery with this plugin the same happens again - the images are all shown in different sizes, while during I`m using the plugin and going to Preview, the preview shows the images in correct sizes. But as soon as I save it, the sizes are totaly different again.

Comment: By copying the site I think I made the following mistake: in the database I simply searched and have the old URL overwritten with the new URL. I read that this is causing a lot of troubles, but so far I don`t know how to change the URLs in the correct way?

Comment: There's [a Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs) that covers updating WordPress URLs.  I regularly use the [Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), though there are other options listed.  Manually updating the database won't work, as any PHP-serialized values will be incorrect. Let me know if that makes a difference.